# Check both values using && operator - ReactNative

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, operators

I'm trying to execute a function inside a if condition like below.

```
function proceed() {
    if (groupName && groupDescription !== null) {
        Actions.addToGroup()
    } else {

    }
}
```

But my `Actions.addToGroup()` gets executed just after checking the first variable `groupName` . But i want to check if the both values are null and if only they both are null i want to execute my function. Isn't `&&` operator supposed to do this?

Comment: `groupName && groupDescription` would return either `false` or `true` which is definitely not equals to null.  `groupName !=null && groupDescription !=null` is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't quite understand conditional boolean syntax in Javascript (it's the same in many other languages). If you want to check if both are not null, you'll have to explicitly do that:

```
if(groupName !== null && groupDescription !== null)
```

The way you have it now, it checks if `groupName` is [truthy](https://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) **and** if `groupDescription` is not null

Comment: The `&&` and `||` operators in boolean logic simply join two *separate* checks together

Answer (score 1):

Basically, true && some-expression always evaluates to expression, and false && some-expression always evaluates to false.
You need to put conditional check on both of the variables to get this right.